# How to wrap texts to auto-adjust row height?

Tags: sapui5

I do have an `sap.m.Table` that looks as the following:

```xml
<Table id="idTable" growing="true" mode="SingleSelectMaster" items="{modelExample>/}">
  <columns>
    <Column width="20%">
      <Text text="Category" />
    </Column>
    <Column width="20%">
      <Text text="Description"/>
    </Column>
    <Column width="30%">
      <Text text="Choice"/>
    </Column>
  </columns>
  <ColumnListItem>
    <Label text="{modelExample>category}" design="Bold"/>
    <Label text="{modelExample>description}" />
    <l:HorizontalLayout>
      <Button text="{modelExample>choice/0}" />
      <Button text="{modelExample>choice/1}" />
    </l:HorizontalLayout>
  </ColumnListItem>
</Table>
```

This `Table` delivers the following result:

[image: Table with unadjusted Row - Height]

**Problem:** The description column does have a lot more text than it is being shown, which is represented as **"..."**.

**Question**: How to change the row height in such a manner that it automatically adjusts itself to the amount of the text content?

**What I want:**
[image: Table with adjusted Row - Height]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sap.m.Label` supports wrapping as of UI5 1.50.

```xml
<Label text="{myText}" wrapping="true" />
```

**But:** if the app should be aligned with the Fiori UX, `Label` should be used **only if it's labeling something** (e.g. in combination with the `labelFor` association). If not, a different text control should be used. From https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/label/:

> - Do not use the label control to display the data
> - Do not use bold labels.

The other control `sap.m.Text` has `wrapping` property too which is enabled by default. If the text needs to be in bold, try [`sap.m.FormattedText`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.FormattedText/sample/sap.m.sample.FormattedText) with `htmlText="&lt;strong>{myText}&lt;/strong>`*.

---

* To allow complex binding syntax, assign `"edge"` to `data-sap-ui-compatversion` in `index.html`.

Comment: there are couple options for the Title like `sap.m.Title` however the size/style/non-bold design make it unattractive. Which option to choose for a title to reach the same effect as `<Label design ="Bold"/>`

Comment: @Incognito You might want to try with `sap.m.FormattedText`. I see that the text also wraps [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emiu0.png). Additionally, it also supports `<strong>` html tag which results in a bold text.